# Compiling swig extension with COLeDateTime for python

Tags: mfc, swig

I have a fairly extensive C++ project that I am using. Just for kicks, I thought I would try the very simple example of swig which uses just the header from the project to build a python module.

Swig ran properly and created a project_wrap.cxx file. However, when I try to compile and link that file with the rest of my project, I am running into errors:

It seems they are mostly related to the MS COLeDateTime:

```
Error   14  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'COleDateTime'
```

resulting from declarations such as:

```
void   SetStartTime     (COleDateTime dt    )  {m_simstart_time = dt;  }
```

Or from IntelliSense:

```
194 IntelliSense: identifier "COleDateTime" is undefined
```

I presume the workaround is to work with the windows.i file, but does anyone have some tips/experience/examples for this?

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
%{
   #include "the_coledatetime_header.h"   // whatever the header is
%}
```

to your .i

The #include will be added to you project_wrap.cxx & should compile.
Check http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Preprocessor_delimiters for more info.

Comment: Thanks, that did not solve it directly, but it seems if I choose to include most of the #include directives from the main project header, the build goes further... I still have a problem with an undefined variable `temp` that SWIG is using in it's wrap code, but there's no definition of it anywhere as a global.