# swig generated code, generating illegal storage class for python wrapper of C++ API

Tags: c++, python, visual-studio-2010, swig

I'm trying to take the approach of using swig with the main header file. It seems like swig will work doing this, but I've run into some problems. I asked a first question about it [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581600/compiling-swig-extension-with-coledatetime-for-python) and while I haven't yet been successful, I've made enough progress to feel encouraged to continue...

So now, here's my interface file:

```
/* File : myAPI.i */
%module myAPI

%{
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
... many other includes ...
#include "myAPI.h"
#include <boost/algorithm/string/predicate.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/operations.hpp>
using boost::format;
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::algorithm;
using namespace boost::serialization;
%}

/* Let's just grab the original header file here */
%include "myAPI.h"
```

As far as I can tell swig runs just fine. However, in the generated code it produces numerous definitions like this one:

```
SWIGINTERN int Swig_var_ModState_set(PyObject *_val) {
  {
    void *argp = 0;
    int res = SWIG_ConvertPtr(_val, &argp, SWIGTYPE_p_MY_API,  0  | 0);
    if (!SWIG_IsOK(res)) {
      SWIG_exception_fail(SWIG_ArgError(res), "in variable '""ModState""' of type      '""MY_API""'");
    }
    if (!argp) {
      SWIG_exception_fail(SWIG_ValueError, "invalid null reference " "in variable    '""ModState""' of type '""MY_API""'");
    } else {
      MY_API * temp;
      temp  = reinterpret_cast< MY_API * >(argp);
      ModState = *temp;
      if (SWIG_IsNewObj(res)) delete temp;
    }
  }
  return 0;
fail:
  return 1;
}
```

Visual Studio 2010 complains with an error for each of these code blocks. The error is based on the `temp` var:

```
2>c:\svn\myapi\myapi_wrap.cxx(3109): error C2071: 'temp' : illegal storage class
```

I tried just to add a global declaration of this variable as an int to the swig generated _wrap.cxx file, but it didn't not work. (clearly a naive approach...).

Does anyone have some insight as to what I need to do to avoid this error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe that these functions set global variables exposed in your API.  If you don't need them there is a way to suppress generating these wrappers from swig; you could also hide them and provide  explicit getter/setter functions; this might help.